# Can Proguard fully remove overhead from unused Kotlin code?

Tags: java, kotlin, proguard

I was thinking about adding some Kotlin extensions to a public Java library I'm working on. It would certainly be simpler to simply put the Kotlin extensions in the same artifact as the base library, but I know Kotlin adds about 1.4 MB to compiled projects. Pure Java users wouldn't be happy. I thought, well maybe that doesn't really matter if users are going to apply Proguard when building a release version, so I did some experimentation with a minimal test library and Java project that uses the library as a dependency.

The library has a pure Java version 1.0, and a 2.0 version where I added a couple of Kotlin extension functions. Both versions are published to Maven local.

The test project has a single class that uses a few features of the library and uses *none* of the Kotlin stuff. I built it with and without Proguard, and with both versions of the library. Here are the results:

```
| Library   |  Proguard   |  Test project fat jar size  |
+-----------+-------------+-----------------------------+
| Pure Java |     No      |     3.2 KB                  |
| Pure Java |     Yes     |     1.6 KB                  |
| w/Kotlin  |     No      |  1485.9 KB                  |
| w/Kotlin  |     Yes     |   180.0 KB                  |
```

So Proguard is able to strip out the bulk of it. Maybe that's all the stlib classes getting removed. So what's left? Is there a way to cut it farther?

Here's my Proguard configuration:

```
-libraryjars  <java.home>/lib/rt.jar

-keepclasseswithmembers public class * {
    public static void main(java.lang.String[]);
}
```

Comment: What is your deployment target? In most situations, the jar file being 1.4MB larger is a complete non-issue.

Comment: Could be mobile or desktop games or apps. I've made successful apps with libgdx that are less than 5MB, so an additional 1.4MB is theoretically significant for relative install time. But you're probably right. In most cases that difference would never register with users. 6 years ago it might have with 3G speeds and tight data caps.